# DllImport a c++ DLL in to a C# app, BYTE * p

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I have a exported function in a c++ DLL

```
// C++ DLL (Blarggg.dll)

extern "C"
{
     USHORT ReadProperty( BYTE * messsage, USHORT length, BYTE * invokeID ) 
    {
         if( invokeID != NULL ) {
            * invokeID = 10 ; 
        }
         return 0;
    }
}
```

That I would like to make it available to my C# application

```
// C# app 
[DllImport("Blarggg.dll")]
public static extern System.UInt16 ReadProperty(
        /* [OUT] */ System.Byte[] message,
        /* [IN]  */ System.UInt16 length,
        /* [OUT] */ System.Byte[] invokeID ); 


private void DoIt() 
{
    System.Byte[] message = new System.Byte[2000];
    System.Byte[] InvokeID = new System.Byte[1];
    System.UInt16 ret = ReadProperty( message, 2000, InvokeID ); // Error 
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting the following error message.

> An unhanded exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Blarggg.dll
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm using VS2008 to build both the DLL and the C# application.

I'm not a C# programmer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pasted your code directly into VS2008 and it runs perfectly on my 32-bit machine (added a .def file to set the exported name).
Is your C++ library definitely a pure win32 project? The error message you gave seems to imply that it threw a CLR exception.

Comment: I copied the code from my currently project in to a new project and I was able to compile and run it with out any problems. It must have something to do with the project or anther part of my application. 

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[DllImport("Blarggg.dll", CallingConvention := CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
public static extern System.UInt16 ReadProperty( 
        /* [IN]  */ System.Byte[] message, 
        /* [IN]  */ System.UInt16 length, 
        /* [OUT] */ out System.Byte invokeID );  


private void DoIt()  
{ 
    System.Byte[] message = new System.Byte[2000]; 
    System.Byte InvokeID; 
    System.UInt16 ret = ReadProperty( message, 2000, out InvokeID );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use the [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(VS.71).aspx) to convert between managed and unmanaged types.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this with C++ types?

I was under the impression that you could only DLLImport C dlls.

We use DLLImport with C++ Dll's just fine but we declare our external functions as

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) ...
```

Have a look at this web page:

http://dotnetperls.com/dllimport-interop

Comment: I should have mentioned that (BYTE = unsigned char, USHORT = unsigned short) both are C data type.

Comment: I added the extern "C" to the question, it is in my original code but it does help with this problem.

Comment: You can definitely DLLImport C++ dll's, the 'extern C' is solely to avoid name mangling, and you can accomplish the same thing in another way.

Comment: did you also declare the C++ function as __declspec(dllexport) ?